# Otimização de query

Tags: mysql, query, otimização

Olá, pessoal!
Tenho essa query (MySQL) para contar quantidade de visitas em um mê em um determinado período, no entanto, ela demora mais de 1 minuto para ser executada. Como eu consigo otimizá-la?
Desde já agradeço.

```
SELECT MONTH(V1_DATA) AS MES,
    YEAR(V1_DATA) AS ANO,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `TV1-VISITAS` WHERE
        (V1_PG LIKE '%download%'
        OR V1_PG LIKE '%home%'
        OR V1_PG LIKE '%empresa%'
        OR V1_PG LIKE '%onde_comprar%'
        OR V1_PG LIKE '%eventos%'
        OR V1_PG LIKE '%contato%'
        OR V1_PG LIKE '%produtos%'
        OR V1_PG LIKE '%representantes%')
        AND YEAR(V1_DATA) = ANO
        AND MONTH(V1_DATA) = MES) AS INSTITUCIONAL,

    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `TV1-VISITAS` WHERE V1_PG LIKE '%evento%' AND YEAR(V1_DATA) = ANO AND MONTH(V1_DATA) = MES) AS EVENTOS,

    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `TV1-VISITAS` WHERE V1_PG LIKE '%produto%' AND YEAR(V1_DATA) = ANO AND MONTH(V1_DATA) = MES) AS PRODUTOS,

    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `TV1-VISITAS` WHERE V1_PG LIKE '%download%' AND YEAR(V1_HORA) = ANO AND MONTH(V1_DATA) = MES) AS ARQUIVOS

    FROM `TV1-VISITAS` WHERE YEAR(V1_DATA) = YEAR(NOW()) GROUP BY MES ORDER BY MES
```

Comment: Tente trocar os selects por CASE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320631/how-to-pivot-a-table-in-mysql-using-case-statements

Answer (score 1):

Algo que seria interessante seria ter esta informação que você filtra no "like" em um campo em separado.

Os subselects pegam como base o ano e o mês da query principal, você pode eliminar eles e utilizar um SUM com CASE para chegar no mesmo resultado. Sua consulta ficaria assim:

```
SELECT MONTH(V1_DATA) AS MES,
    YEAR(V1_DATA) AS ANO,
    SUM(CASE WHEN V1_PG LIKE '%download%'
    OR V1_PG LIKE '%home%' OR V1_PG LIKE '%empresa%' OR V1_PG LIKE '%onde_comprar%' OR V1_PG LIKE '%eventos%' OR V1_PG LIKE '%contato%' OR V1_PG LIKE '%produtos%' OR V1_PG LIKE '%representantes%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS INSTITUCIONAL,
    SUM(CASE WHEN V1_PG LIKE '%evento%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EVENTOS,
    SUM(CASE WHEN V1_PG LIKE '%produto%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PRODUTOS,
    SUM(CASE WHEN V1_PG LIKE '%download%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ARQUIVOS
    FROM `TV1-VISITAS` WHERE YEAR(V1_DATA) = YEAR(NOW()) GROUP BY MES ORDER BY MES
```

Comment: Cara, você é um gênio!
A consulta retornou exatamente como deve retornar (da mesma forma como retornava com a query anterior) mas agora com um tempo de retorno de 0.2 seg!
Obrigado!

Comment: O problema do operador `LIKE` principalmente com o `%` no inicio da condição vai forçar um BD a fazer um `FULL SCAN` na tabela. Uma maneira de garantir uma resposta rápida é definir filtros mais específicos em um campo que contém indices na tabela. Por exemplo, você mencionou a respeito de um determinado período. Nesse sentido, falta na sua query um `WHERE V1_DATA BETWEEN ...`. Melhor ainda se puder especificar um filtro por um ID da chave estrangeira (ex: `ID_CLIENTE = 100`).